# Codeigniter - Views stuck while loading

Tags: codeigniter

Few of my views are stuck while loading, browser shows loading but it never loads.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Adil

Comment: Oh come on? We need more details. We cant read minds!

Comment: I can! Do you live on the first floor? Some views reportedly refuse to work on the first floor, so you should probably come up with a moving plan. Or learn how to ask [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your view. Check the apache log and/or enable error reporting.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, however impossible it is to give an answer to this question.